# Using SimpleXML with Android and Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, simple-framework, dex

I'm having troubles trying to compile an Android application with Gradle 0.5.+ and Android Studio, using SimpleXML.

This is the error:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MyApplication:dexDebug'.
> Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/dx --dex --output <REALLY_LONG_STRING.....>
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class":
    Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
    when not building a core library.
    This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
    in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
    Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
    core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
    going on.
    However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
    namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
    from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
    assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
    compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
    It is also often of questionable legality.
    If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
    appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
    distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
    the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
    If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
    building an application, then be forewarned that your application
    will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
    prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
    application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
    system. You will be to blame for this problem.
    If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
    core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
    repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
    your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
    conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
    you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
    that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
    lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
    1 error; aborting
```

build.gradle is configured like that:

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+'
}
repositories {
    [...]
    mavenCentral()
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

**EDIT**
The problem is not present if i install Simple-XML directly as a Jar inside libs/ - of course a maven solution would be cleaner.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You need to also exclude stax-API.

```
implementation('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+'){
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Comment: Hi Juggeli, with the new Gradle version, it seems like excluding these 3 modules from simple-xml does not solve the problem. Lint is still crying with the fact it's a non-Android library. Anyone facing this issue ?

Comment: if you don't put parens around the single quote, you will need comma before first curly brace else you get  "Error:(70, 0) Could not find method com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0() for arguments....". I'm not sure what the difference between parens or not... but ran into this and took a while to figure out.

Answer (score 15):

Try this if previous solution doesn't work:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'stax'
    compile.exclude module: 'stax-api'
    compile.exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
dependencies {
    [...]
    compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+'
}
repositories {
    [...]
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: For some reason, using the exclude clauses on the compile statement didn't work, but listing them in configurations did for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to exclude some of dependencies.

```
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+'){
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error while using SimpleFramework.
Actually i resolved it by adding these lines in build.gradle:

```
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') 
{
   exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
   exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'<br>
}
```