# How to use and modify the source code from simplexml library in Android?

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I just downloaded the soucre code from the library simplexml
http://simple.sourceforge.net/download.php

I want to make a few modifications in the source code and use it in android,
[image]

Unfortunatly there are two classes StreamProvider, and StreamReader,
that need an external reference, 
The original project provide this libraries

[image]

trying to use this libraries in the android
project you get compilations errors.

How to modifiy the source code from this library and use in Android?

I want to use the source of this library directly, and be able to modify, not just use it with gradle or a jar file.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SimpleXML with Android and Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084285/using-simplexml-with-android-and-gradle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete StreamProvider.java and StreamReader.java clases,
this classes are not compatible with Android

And you have to choose a xml-provider

[image]

And in ProviderFactory.java use PullProvider or Document Provider

[image]

```
 public static Provider getInstance() {
  /*
  try {
     try {
        return new StreamProvider();
     } catch(Throwable e) {
        return new PullProvider();
     }
  } catch(Throwable e) {
     return new DocumentProvider();
  }
  */
  try {
     return new PullProvider();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return new DocumentProvider();
 }
```